# npm install not working in laravel 5.6

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-5, npm

On a fresh install of laravel 5.6 via composer

How I installed it:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel
```

After installing I ran:

```
npm install
```

I get back:

```
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file. Up to date in 0.163s.
```

It does not create a node_modules folder.

If I try using `yarn` to install the dependencies using:

```
yarn install
```

I get back:

```
yarn install v1.3.2 info No lockfile found. Resolving packages... warning laravel-mix > img-loader > imagemin-mozjpeg > mozjpeg > bin-wrapper > download > gulp-decompress > gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidlines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9fac5 | Fetching packages... info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform 'win32' is incompatible with this module. info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatability check. Excluding it from installation. Linking dependencies.... Building fresh packages... success Saved lockfile. Done in 35.38s
```

This creates a `node_modules` folder with only ".yarn-integrity' no modules.

The link to the medium page doesn't work, receive 404 so no luck there.

My node version is: "v8.9.4" and my yarn version is: 'v1.3.2'

- Edit: This isn't a git issue. I'm not using git

Comment: after you creating the project and before running `npm install`, did you `cd` into the project directory?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm in the project directory currently.

Answer (score 2):

running:

```
npm install --dev or npm install --only=dev
```

This installed the dependencies I needed. For whatever reason in laravel 5.6 all the dependencies are considered devDependencies in the package.json file.

Comment: npm install --only=dev, first one is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

> package-lock.json is automatically generated for any operations where npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json. It describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of intermediate dependency updates.

Run the following command

1. `git add -A`
2. `git commit -m "Commit package-lock.json"`
3. `git push -u origin master`

Now re-run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you are in your project directory e.g

1) cd path/to/my_laravel_project
2) npm install

Answer (score 0):

this because you are not in laravel root folder, when you create a project, at first you are not in folder you need to open your project folder and use

```
npm i
```